# 503 service unavailable error

Tags: apache, http-status-code-503

Past few days before, I have lost all files and folders of code for my website due to some idiotic steps. However, I have uploaded all that again but don't know which server file has been changed or erased while file removal process, I am getting `503 service unavailable error`. I am using apache server.

Comment: You should change the apache's error logs for more details. Or enable more detailed logging if there isn't anything inside the logs.

Comment: @LajosVeres I don't have access of apache